# Turn off cerficate validation in Github Api

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I am using this github [api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github).

```
var github = new GitHubApi({
    // optional
    debug: true,
    protocol: "http",
    host: "github.my-GHE-enabled-company.com", // should be api.github.com for GitHub
    pathPrefix: "/api/v3", // for some GHEs; none for GitHub
    headers: {
        "user-agent": "My-Cool-GitHub-App" // GitHub is happy with a unique user agent
    },
    Promise: require('bluebird'),
    followRedirects: false, // default: true; there's currently an issue with non-get redirects, so allow ability to disable follow-redirects
    timeout: 5000
});
```

I **want to turn off the certificate validation** for all the HTTP Requests going on from this object in Node js.

how to send , is there any specific header value need to send to turn off ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0;
```

But this will make **ALL** the requests **insecure**

So... I think `rejectUnauthorized:true` is the agent option you are looking for.

Since node-github uses https-proxy-agent, I think you would have to set `proxyUrl.rejectUnauthorized = true` before its used in the constructor [at line 666](https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github/blob/0f0daf1972ef3644ba5c633e0188f6f92f6b58ed/lib/index.js#L666)